# Pytest: logging using allure

Tags: python, logging, allure, python-logging

So In order to add steps to my `allure` report I am using this function:

```
import allure
from datetime import datetime


class Report:
    @staticmethod
    def report_step(step_title):
        with allure.step(f'[{datetime.now()}]: {step_title}'):
            pass
```

And I want to find a way to add `logging` to my code as well.

So I was thinking of add `logging` into this function:

```
def report_step(step_title):
    m = f'[{datetime.now()}]: {step_title}'
    with allure.step(m):
        logging.debug(m)
```

But I have 2 problems with this approach:

1. I cannot determine log `level` according this method (although I can add another parameter to this `report_step` method)
2. In my log I am using this format:

   '[%(asctime)s] [ %(levelname)s ] [%(filename)s] [%(funcName)s] [%(lineno)d]: %(message)s'

And In my case here with this `report_step`  method all log lines will write from the same class name (Report in my example) And in case I will need to investigate I will need to find first from where the log lines come from.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: 1. You want to define a loglevel of step log messages using some pytest cmdline option? 2. So what do you want to see as a source of logging instead of the `Report` class?

Comment: Yes and also see the log level

Comment: Was my answer helpful or have you met some difficulties using code from it?

Answer (score 1):

As pytest plugins are very flexible you may not create another context manager to wrap `allure.step` but just define some hooks that will be executed along with it.

So basically, in my solution I create a local plugin that contains `allure-pytest` plugin's hook implementation. Local plugins (hooks and fixtures) can be stored in `conftest.py` (or any other module but with declaration in `conftest.py` using `pytest_plugins` variable).

First of all, we need to add a command line option that will be used to set a log level for our logger. It can be done with [pytest_addoption](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) hook.

Then, we need to define our plugin as a class that requires the pytest `config` variable and will define a corresponding log level from it.

Also this class must contain `start_step` function with `@allure_commons.hookimpl` decorator which specifies that it is hook implementation.

And finally, we need to register our plugin with `allure_commons.plugin_manager` using [pytest_configure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) hook.

I put all code to `conftest.py` including local plugin class just for example.

**conftest.py**

```py
import inspect
import logging

import allure_commons
from _pytest.config import UsageError


class AllureStepLogger:
    def __init__(self, config):
        # Create a logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

        # Get --allure-step-log-level value
        self.level = config.option.allure_step_log_level
        if isinstance(self.level, str):
            self.level = self.level.upper()
        # Get a level number by a level name
        try:
            self.level = int(getattr(logging, self.level, self.level))
        except ValueError as e:
            # Python logging does not recognise this as a logging level
            raise UsageError(
                "'{}' is not recognized as a logging level name for "
                "'{}'. Please consider passing the "
                "logging level num instead.".format(self.level, self.__class__.__name__)
            ) from e

    @allure_commons.hookimpl
    def start_step(self, uuid, title, params):
        """Add a hook implementation to log every step"""
        # get test_* function name from stack
        test_name = next((frame[3] for frame in inspect.stack() if frame[3].startswith("test_")), "Unknown test")
        # log a message using defined logger and log level
        self.logger.log(self.level, f"{test_name}: {title}")


def pytest_configure(config):
    """Register `allure_step_logger` plugin if `allure_pytest` plugin is registered."""
    if config.pluginmanager.getplugin('allure_pytest'):
        allure_commons.plugin_manager.register(AllureStepLogger(config), "allure_step_logger")


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Add a cmdline option --allure-step-log-level."""
    parser.getgroup("logging").addoption(
        "--allure-step-log-level",
        dest="allure_step_log_level",
        default="debug",
        metavar="ALLURE_STEP_LEVEL",
        help="Level of allure.step log messages. 'DEBUG' by default."
    )
```

**test_module.py**

```py
import allure


def test_function_1():
    with allure.step("Step 1"):
        pass
        with allure.step("Substep 1.1"):
            pass
        with allure.step("Substep 1.2"):
            pass
    with allure.step("Step 2"):
        pass


def test_function_2():
    with allure.step("Step 1"):
        pass
    with allure.step("Step 2"):
        pass
    with allure.step("Step 3"):
        pass
```

**Output** for `pytest --alluredir=results --log-cli-level=debug` will contain our logs since `--allure-step-log-level` is `debug` by default.

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_module.py::test_function_1 
test_module.py::test_function_2 

============================== 2 passed in 0.08s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 0

-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_1: Step 1
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_1: Substep 1.1
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_1: Substep 1.2
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_1: Step 2
PASSED                                                                   [ 50%]
-------------------------------- live log call --------------------------------
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_2: Step 1
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_2: Step 2
[14:30:49] [ DEBUG ] [conftest.py] [start_step] [34]: test_function_2: Step 3
PASSED                                                                   [100%]
```

To change logger level to `INFO` for example, just use `--allure-step-log-level=info`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay.... all my log messages is from [AllureStepLogger:conftest.py]  [MY_TEST_CLASS], I am still continue using my report_step function, I need to use anther way to logging ?

Comment: Actually I think any logger will show you the exact place from where it was executed unless you write your own method. You can have a look at `inspect` package which can help to define the parent function/module in stack. I am just not sure what do you want to see instead this class.